# unable to save / update products

Tags: magento-1.9, products, save, transaction

Unable to save or update products in **Magento ver. 1.9.1.0**.

When I go to save a product record in admin, it returns with onscreen error message

> There is no active transaction

and no changes are saved.

The function which was overridden

```
public function saveEntityIndexes($storeId, $entityIndexes, $entity = 'product')
    {
            $adapter = $this->_getWriteAdapter();
            $data   = array();
            $storeId = (int)$storeId;
            $str = "";
            foreach ($entityIndexes as $entityId => &$index) {
                    $data = array(
                            (int)$entityId,
                            $storeId,
                            '"'.addslashes($index['data_index']).'"',
                            '"'.addslashes($index['name']).'"',
                            '"'.addslashes($index['name_attributes']).'"',
                            '"'.addslashes($index['category']).'"',
                            '"'.addslashes($index['manufacturer']).'"',
                            '"'.addslashes($index['product_type']).'"',
                            '"'.addslashes($index['product_color']).'"',
                            '"'.addslashes($index['product_img']).'"',
                            '"'.addslashes($index['product_url_path']).'"',
                            '"'.addslashes($index['default_sort']).'"'
                    );
                    $str .= '('. implode(', ', $data) . '),';
            }
            $str = rtrim($str, ',');
            if ($data) {
                $query =  'INSERT INTO `sphinx_catalogsearch_fulltext` (`product_id`,`store_id`,`data_index`,`name`,`name_attributes`,`category`,`manufacturer`,`product_type`,`product_color`,`product_img`,`product_url_path`,`default_sort`)'
                . 'VALUES ' . $str
                . ' ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `data_index` = VALUES(`data_index`), `name` = VALUES(`name`), `name_attributes` = VALUES(`name_attributes`), `category` = VALUES(`category`), `manufacturer` = VALUES(`manufacturer`), `product_type` = VALUES(`product_type`), `product_color` = VALUES(`product_color`), `product_img` = VALUES(`product_img`), `product_url_path` = VALUES(`product_url_path`), `default_sort` = VALUES(`default_sort`)';

                $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
                $writeConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_write');
                $writeConnection->query($query);
                $writeConnection->closeConnection();
            }

            return $this;
    }
```

Comment: Hello. Looks like a PDO problem. Did you modify/override some core scripts related to product saving process?

Comment: Yes, I overrode Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Fulltext_Engine's saveEntityIndexes function to save data in a different table which has engine type MyIsam.

Comment: I edited the question and added the function which was overridden. Can you tell me what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that the original function is

```
public function saveEntityIndexes($storeId, $entityIndexes, $entity = 'product')
{
    $data    = array();
    $storeId = (int)$storeId;
    foreach ($entityIndexes as $entityId => $index) {
        $data[] = array(
            'product_id'    => (int)$entityId,
            'store_id'      => $storeId,
            'data_index'    => $index
        );
    }

    if ($data) {
        Mage::getResourceHelper('catalogsearch')
            ->insertOnDuplicate($this->getMainTable(), $data, array('data_index'));
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Try:

```
        Mage::getResourceHelper('catalogsearch')
            ->insertOnDuplicate('sphinx_catalogsearch_fulltext', $data, array('data_index'));
```

Then you are doing minimal changes to the function.

Or make no changes to the function and overwrite `Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Fulltext_Engine` as follows:

```
class Company_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Fulltext_Engine extends Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Fulltext_Engine
{
    /**
     * Init resource model
     *
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('sphinx/catalogsearch/fulltext', 'product_id');
    }
}
```

Correcting `sphinx/catalogsearch/fulltext` to the correctly defined/named table definition in your Config (assuming `sphinx_catalogsearch_fulltext` has the same columns as `catalogsearch_fulltext`)

Comment: Initially I used Mage::getResourceHelper('catalogsearch')
            ->insertOnDuplicate('sphinx_catalogsearch_fulltext', $data, array('data_index')); but it gives error with all value replaced by '?' instead of values.

Comment: The problem is definitely in this function. After I removed the override, I was able to save the product with no error.